# MS ACCESS Query to average when no match is found

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, match, average

i have a situation i can't seem to get around . i must say i'm quite new to access and sql, so maybe this is quite easy:

Let's use this table as an example:

```
Country | State | City  | Value
   A        X      1       30
   A        X      2       40
   A        Y      3       50
```

And then, in another table

```
Country | State | City  | Value
   A        X      1       ?
   A        X      4       ?
   A        Z      5       ?
```

I need a query joining both tables to return the '?' on the second table:

When the combination city/state/country is found it should return that record (standard join between the tables).

When the join does not exist (e.g. a left join would leave the "Value" column blank) to use the average value from the "parent" , so the first line would be 30, the second line would be (40+30)/2=35 and the third one would be (30+40+50)/3 = 40.

It's like doing three consecutive JOINS: first, you are joining (country,city,state),and returning AVG(Value). Then when AVG(VALUE)=NULL, for those records you join (country,city), and then if it's still not found, you join (country) only.

sorry i think i didn't express myself very well, hope you can understand =/

Is there any way to do it quickly?

Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean "found to use that value"?  Your question doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to Access (no pun intended), but something like this should work.  It may need a little proofreading.

```
SELECT a.country, a.city, a.state,
       iif(b.value IS NULL, a.avgval, b.value) as value
FROM (select country, state, city, avg(value) as avgval
      from table_a) a
LEFT JOIN table_b b
  ON a.country = b.country
 AND a.city = b.city
 AND a.state = b.state;
```

Edit: doing a little more searching, it sounds like Access has no support for SQL `CASE` statements, so I substituted an `iif` that I think behaves the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this with multiple aggregations.  Then use `left join`s to prioritize the values:

```
select b.country, b.city, b.state, nz(nz(a.value, acs.avgv), ac.avgv) as value
from ((b left join
       a
       on b.country = a.country and b.state = a.state and b.city = a.city
      ) left join
      (select country, state, avg(value) as avgv
       from a
       group by country, state
      ) acs
      on acs.country = b.country and acs.state = b.state
     ) left join
     (select country, avg(value) as avgv
      from a
      group by country
     ) ac
     on ac.country = a.country;
```